# Error Pod Install on React Native - Cocoapods

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

Question:

I'm encountering an error when trying to run pod install in my project, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here's the error message I'm seeing:

/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/bin/pod install

Report:

What did you do?

I ran the command pod install in my project directory to install CocoaPods dependencies.

What did you expect to happen?

I expected CocoaPods to install the specified dependencies without any issues.

What happened instead?

Instead, I encountered the following error:

JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/2.3.1/PromisesObjC.podspec.json'.
859: unexpected token at ...

Stack:

CocoaPods: 1.14.0
Ruby: ruby 3.1.4p223 (2023-03-30 revision 957bb7cb81) [arm64-darwin22]
RubyGems: 3.3.26
Host: macOS 13.0 (22A380)
Xcode: 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Git: git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
Ruby lib dir: /Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib
Repositories: trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
Plugins:

cocoapods-deintegrate: 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins: 1.0.0
cocoapods-search: 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk: 1.6.0
cocoapods-try: 1.2.0

Podfile:

````
[ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'my_crm' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
      pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
      pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
      $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'my_crmTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end]
````

Error:

JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '/Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/2.3.1/PromisesObjC.podspec.json'.
859: unexpected token at ...

Any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!